# prove this inequality relativistic velocity addition law

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that the set of all velocities under the relativistic velocity addition law, form a group.

I proved all other properties except this one :

let $c$ be a positive  real number and $E={]-c,c[}$
prove that :
$$\forall(v_1,v_2)\in E^2 \ \ ,\ \ \frac{v_1+v_2}{1+\dfrac{v_1 \times v_2}{ c^2}} \in E $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify the notation, we can write $v_i = r_i c.$  Then we want to show that if $r_1,r_2 \in {]-1,1[},$ then $\dfrac{r_1+r_2}{1+r_1r_2} \in {]-1,1[}.$  Now noting that $r_1r_2 \neq -1,$ we can see that the target inequality is equivalent to
$$|r_1 + r_2| < |1 + r_1r_2|$$
Squaring both sides gives
$$r_1^2 + 2r_1r_2 + r_2^2 < 1 + 2r_1r_2 + r_1^2r_2^2$$
Moving everything to the right side gives
$$0 < 1 - r_1^2 - r_2^2 + r_1^2r_2^2 = (1 - r_1^2)(1 - r_2^2)$$
which is true since $|r_1|,|r_2| < 1.$

Now either just note that every step was reversible (or actually go backwards through the steps to check this) to show what you wanted to show.